# How to build an API as like a webservice if user send a curl request?

Tags: php, api, web-services, curl

How does a smallest safety API look like for receiving and validating curl requests?

I found a lot of examples how to do with sending a curl request but not how to read and validate requests on the server dealing with database.

Thank you in advanced.

*** UPDATE after answer from dexterb:

A real situation is to send data of 10 books (id, name, price) to the API.

How can I send data 10 times from this to the server:

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(array(
    id => 1,
    name => 'name1'
    price => 1.00
    )
)
```

How to receive request on server:

```
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode( ':', base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'],6 )));


if (!isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])) {

    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm-Name"');

    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

    exit;

} else {

        // Look into database... SELECT... and get the api_token ...


        if( !api_token ) {

            header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Realm-Name"');

            header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

            exit;

        }     

}




// Make main things ...
// 
// How can I read and store the above data of ten book records?
//
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple api structure:

```
users table
- id
- name
- email
- password
- api_token (random 60 long characters)
```

Then, to authenticate your requests, you'll have to use their api_token for that. And a simple request would be 
http://example.com/api/test?api_token=XXXXXX
Then in your API authentication, you'll just have to check if the `api_token` used in the request is present in your users table. Then that's it.

Comment: A real situation is to send data of 10 books (id, name, price) to the API. 

How can I send data 10 times from this to the server:

    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(array(
        id => 1,
        name => 'name1'
        price => 1.00
        )
    )

Comment: How can I read and store the above data of ten books records?